# Why is Google indexing my robots.txt file?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, search-results

Google Search is indexing my robots.txt file. I know this because when I search `site:example.com` on Google, my robots.txt shows in the list of results. I don't want my robots.txt to show in Google.

The content of my robots.txt is

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is Google indexing my `robots.txt` file?

It is normal behavior for Google to index your `robots.txt` file. It's a URL on your website just like any other.

> I don't want my robots.txt to show in Google.

Your `robots.txt` file already does not show on Google, in the general sense that Google Search users could stumble upon it without specifically looking for it. Google is smart enough to know that it's generally irrelevant to searchers. Nobody will see it in search results unless they are trying to comb through your site's index using the `site:` operator.

To answer the question as written: To prevent your `robots.txt` file from being indexed, you can configure your web server to [serve it up with a `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` header](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_meta_tag#xrobotstag). However there is no practical benefit to doing so, and depending on your server software it may involve some extra setup/configuration.